# Can I have text and a div in the same table column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I currently have a static table, because i can always expect the same outcome. I have kind of headlines, in which i combine the 2 columns and then theres data. It looks similar to this one:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: hide;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><b>Headline 1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description a </td>
        <td> Data a </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description b </td>
        <td> Data b </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description c </td>
        <td> Data c </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><b>Headline 2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description d </td>
        <td> Data d </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description e </td>
        <td> Data e </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description f </td>
        <td> Data f </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to add a small icon which the user can click to open a help menu, which explains the shown data. I tried solving this, by adding a `div` into the same `td` but it will force my `div` into a new line. See below:
(Note: I wouldnot have text, but a 13px by 13px `background-image`. The Text inside the `div` is to show the new line, the new line is not because of the text.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: hide;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.icon {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
            <b>Headline 1</b>
            <div class="icon">example</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description a </td>
        <td> Data a </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description b </td>
        <td> Data b </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description c </td>
        <td> Data c </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><b>Headline 2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description d </td>
        <td> Data d </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description e </td>
        <td> Data e </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description f </td>
        <td> Data f </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any known solution for my problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It seems to be. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your div display:inline

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: hide;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.icon {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>Headline 1</b><div class="icon">example</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description a </td>
    <td> Data a </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description b </td>
    <td> Data b </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description c </td>
    <td> Data c </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>Headline 2</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description d </td>
    <td> Data d </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description e </td>
    <td> Data e </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description f </td>
    <td> Data f </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was hoping to find :)

Comment: Okay. I noticed it works fine if I use text, but if I want it to show my background, it wont do so without me having text inside of the div. The div ist 0px by 15px (which is my line height) if i have no text inside, thus won't show my image.

Comment: Please update the code above and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found another way to display my image within your code.